# Convert Numbers To Letters and Output Letter Square Using For Loop

Tags: c++, loops

Beginner C++ student here, first ever programming class. The code I put together shown below outputs a number square as shown in the screenshot in this link when the user inputs an int. For example, 5:

[image]

However, I now need to have this loop output the same pattern, but with letters when the user enter the same input:

```
AAAAAAAAA
ABBBBBBBA
ABCCCCCBA
ABCDDDCBA
ABCDEDCBA
ABCDDDCBA
ABCCCCCBA
ABBBBBBBA
AAAAAAAAA
```

Can anyone ever so kindly advise how to best convert these numbers to letters. e.g. 1 = 'A', 2 = 'B', etc.

Thank you so very much.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int size;

    cin >> size;

    int iSize = size;

    for (int r = 1 - iSize; r < iSize; r++) {
        for (int c = 1 - iSize; c < iSize; c++) {   
            cout << iSize - max(abs(r), abs(c));
        }   
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should change the title; you have the loops and the square down cold, you're asking how to convert numbers to letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Thank you all for your time and advise!

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <cmath>
 #include <algorithm>

 using namespace std;

 int main() {

 unsigned size;

 cin >> size;

 int iSize = static_cast<int>(size);

 for (int r = 1 - iSize; r < iSize; r++) {
    for (int c = 1 - iSize; c < iSize; c++) {       

        cout << static_cast<char>( '@' + iSize - max(abs(r), abs(c)) ); // this is the change.


         }
        cout << endl;

     }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code.

### char ch = (char) (i + 65);

65 is the first character 'A' number.

Comment: Although this is likely to work, it is implementation-dependent. The C and C++ standards only guarantee that the letters A through F are contiguous.

Comment: Wow. This renders my whole explanation false :(

Comment: because you use i - isize this time you should start i from 0.

Answer (score 0):

You should have enough with a hint:
Characters in C are nothing else than representation of numbers (their [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) codes), so you can add an `int` to a `char` and obtain the character that distance from the original one.

For example, see what this code outputs:

```
for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++){
    cout << 'A';
    cout << (char)('A' + i);
}
```

Just an addition to this hint is that these codes follow the ASCII table. The cast to `char` in the second line of the loop is so `cout` knows it has to print a character.

Answer (score 0):

A valuable programming tip: *develop new functionality in isolation.* Don't worry about the square, the question is how to turn numbers into letters.

The `char` type is an integer type -- a number -- which the code tends to interpret as a character. How does it map back and forth between numbers and characters? [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). But for now it is enough to know that the code interprets the number 65 as 'A', 66 as 'B', 67 as 'C', and so on. So you can translate {1, 2, 3,...} to {A, B, C,...} just by:

```
char c = n + 64;
```

But what if you're working deep in a coal mine with no WiFi, and you can't get to any ASCII tables to look up 'A' = 65? Well, you don't actually need to know what it is, to use it:

```
char c = n + 'A' - 1;
```